# punctuation of ledor vador in Modim prayer of the Amida

Tags: grammar-dikduk, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

מוֹדִים אֲנַֽחְנוּ לָךְ, שָׁאַתָּה הוּא, יְיָ אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ, לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד, צוּרֵֽנוּ צוּר חַיֵּֽינוּ, מָגֵן יִשְׁעֵֽנוּ, אַתָּה הוּא לְדוֹר וָדוֹר, נֽוֹדֶה לְּךָ וּנְסַפֵּר תְּהִלָּתֶֽךָ, עַל חַיֵּֽינוּ הַמְּסוּרִים בְּיָדֶֽךָ, וְעַל נִשְׁמוֹתֵֽינוּ הַפְּקוּדוֹת לָךְ, וְעַל נִסֶּֽיךָ שֶׁבְּכָל יוֹם עִמָּֽנוּ, וְעַל נִפְלְאוֹתֶֽיךָ וְטוֹבוֹתֶֽיךָ שֶׁבְּכָל עֵת, עֶֽרֶב וָבֹֽקֶר וְצָהֳרָֽיִם, הַטּוֹב, כִּי לֹא כָלוּ רַחֲמֶֽיךָ, וְהַמְרַחֵם, כִּי לֹא תַֽמּוּ חֲסָדֶֽיךָ, כִּי מֵעוֹלָם קִוִּֽינוּ לָךְ

Some prayer books I have seen put a comma before "LeDor Vador", implying it is the start of the next statement while others put a comma after, implying it is the end of the previous statement.

which one is correct?

Comment: Do you recall the names of any of the prayer books whose position on the matter you can identify?

Comment: general prayer books in israel. i've seen it split about 50/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Siddur אוצר התפלות](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=1344&strPageHistory=related)  quotes the commentary “Iyun Tefillo” who first quotes the reading , אַתָּה הוּא לְדוֹר וָדוֹר and then says there are those who say לְדוֹר וָדוֹר נְסַפֵּר תְּהִלָּתֶֽךָ (I have the Ashkenaz version) based on [Tehillim 79 (13)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=299).

From  the  Iyun Tefillo, both versions seem to be good.

(This is similar to the question of how to read תמיד in the last brocho before the Amidah of Maariv outside Israel: המלך בכבודו תמיד ימלוך עלינו. Again “Iyun Tefillo” allows both readings – with  בכבודו and with  ימלוך עלינו.)

Comment: that verse in tehilim seems like a strong indication that the latter is most likely the correct version.